# How to use Sequel::Plugins::JsonSerializer#to_json method when aggregation function is used

Tags: sequel, jsonserializer

There is a model `Game` like this. The `Game` has `date` and `point` columns.

```
class Game < Sequel::Model
  plugin :json_serializer
end
```

When I use a aggregation function it returns a error.

```
Game.select(Sequel.lit('max(point) as max_point')).group(:date).to_json
#=>`NoMethodError: undefined method `max_point'`
```

I can avoid the error by defining a method `max_point` in `Game` model.

```
def max_point
  @values[:max_point]
end
```

I don't want to define a new method every time when I use a aggregation function.
Is there a recommended way to solve the problem like this?